# why beeline CLI argument doesn't do anything after connecting to the beeline CLI?

Tags: shell, hive, beeline

I have a shell script code that automates the beeline commands. The code is able to connect to the JDBC, but it sits there, it doesn't seem to execute the further codes in the shell script, ie. it doesn't truncate the table, doesn't load the data, doesn't insert. Below is the whole code::

```
#! /bin/bash

timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S:%N)
unix_time=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)

export 

BEELINE_PREFIX='"jdbc:hive2://server:port,server:port,server:port/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveser

ver2;principal=hive/server@hello.COM"'

beeline -u $BEELINE_PREFIX -e use next;

echo "truncating the staging table tbl1..."
beeline -u $BEELINE_PREFIX -e  "TRUNCATE TABLE next.tbl1;"

echo "Loading the data in stating table tbl1"
beeline -u $BEELINE_PREFIX -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'path_to/tbl1.txt' INTO TABLE next.tbl1;"

echo "Appending the data into history table tbl1.."
beeline -u $BEELINE_PREFIX -e "insert into table next.hist_tbl1 select *,'$unix_time' from next.tbl1;"

When I execute ./tbl1.sh
```

I could see below output:

```
Connecting to 

jdbc:hive2://jdbc:hive2://server:port,server:port,server:port/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2

;principal=hive/server@hello.COM
Connected to: Apache Hive
Driver: Hive JDBC
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292 by Apache Hive
```

The code seem to only execute the veru first "beeline -u", i.e, JDBC connection only.
I have noted that, When I use ctrl +c, then it goes forward, and throw below error

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. File file:/usr/ibmpacks/current/bigsql/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler.jar does not exist (state=08S01,code=1)
```

Any idea, what is the mistake?

Comment: you should quote `"use next"` in the first query..note that the execution of the script stops at the first error, hence the subsequent queries aren't getting executed.

Comment: @Vamsi, Thanx for pointing out my mistake, I took care of that now. Still, the situation is the same, the shell script initiates the beeline JDBC connection and sits there forever, I have to use ctrl +c to move further. Only this time, I do not see the previous error, but it actually executes the "truncate", "LOAD", and "INSERT". But that is not the right way. How to rectify this ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. I was using extra line of `beeline -u $BEELINE_PREFIX` in my original code before a hive database was used `"use database".` I commented it out. The script running properly.